# Como saber quantas vezes o maior valor foi lido (sem lista)?

Tags: python, algoritmo, loop, for

Estou fazendo um exercício em que devo imprimir o maior valor dos números digitados e quantas vezes esse maior valor foi digitado.

Tentei colocar o `qnt += 1` mas não está dando certo.

```
qnt = 0
num_lidos = int(input('Digite a quantidade de números: '))

num = int(input('\nDigite o valor: '))
if num >= 0:
    maior = num
    for num in range(1, num_lidos):
        num = int(input('Digite o valor: '))
        if num > maior:
            maior = num
            qnt += 1
    print(f'Maior valor = {maior}')
    print(f'Quantidade de vezes que o maior número foi lido: {qnt}')
else:
    print('Erro: Valor negativo.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tirei a verificação se é negativo, porque ou faz do jeito certo ou não faz, e o enunciado postado na pergunta não fala disso e essa parte nada tem a ver com problema relatado, então tirei. Pelo mesmo motivo não coloquei a verificação de erro se a pessoa não digitar um número.

O erro é que só deve somar na quantidade de entradas que sejam exatamente o maior se esse valor for **igual** ao maior, não quando você acha um valor novo como maior. Quando acha que valor que é um novo maior, então a contagem que estava fazendo não tem mais validade porque agora tem um novo valor maior, então começa a contagem de novo. Se é menor continua fazendo nada extra.

O ideal é não reusar a variação do laço, mas nesse caso não tem diferença. Na verdade esse caso talvez seja de nem usar um `for` e ficar no `while`, mas nem vou mexer porque em Python as pessoas acham que é sacrilégio usar `while`, ou seja, por religião.

```
num_lidos = int(input('Digite a quantidade de números: '))
maior = 0
qnt = 0
for num in range(0, num_lidos):
    num = int(input('Digite o valor: '))
    if num > maior:
        maior = num
        qnt = 1
    elif num == maior:
        qnt += 1
print(f'Maior valor = {maior}')
print(f'Quantidade de vezes que o maior número foi lido: {qnt}')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UrB4C5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ogkeqiex-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/CountGreatest.py).

Comment: Entendii, muito obrigado! Eu estava descartando a contagem do valor maior sempre que achava um novo, e realmente obrigado por explicar como corrigir :)

Comment: Não, você estava contando quantas alterações de maior aconteceram.